# Array Rand Not Randomizing

Tags: php, arrays

Created an array that needs randomizing however the array_rand is not working. Is my syntax wrong somewhere? I don't notice anything wrong. Plus, array_rand is used elsewhere on the code so I know it's possible to use it.

```
$array_11 = array (
"40","20","36",
);

$random_width_1 = array_rand($array_11, 3);

echo $array_11[$random_width_1[0]];
echo $array_11[$random_width_1[1]];
echo $array_11[$random_width_1[2]];
```

Comment: try http://dk2.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Comment: array_rand won't randomize an array, it just selects a random value from an array. use shuffle as @mrok said ^

Comment: `array_rand()` is for selecting single random elements from the array, or groups of them. Since your array is only 3 elements and you're selecting 3, you'll always get the same.

Comment: @mrok, since you were the first to respond correctly, post your answer and I'll count you as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use try http://php.net/shuffle instead of array_rand

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `array_rand` sorts it's output array. if you ask exactly as much item as your input you will get all the indexes back in order. ([see this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php#74406))

If you want to create a random order of your array you can use `shuffle`